# How to find the most smallest elements from multiple lists in R?

Tags: r, correlation

I am having three data frames, including rows are genes (gene names are the same), and columns are Estimate(correlation coefficients), P-values, Q-values. You can see the figure to easily understand the structure of lists.

[image: fig1]
[image: fig3]
[image: fig2]

Right now, I am wanting to extract the genes from three lists, and have simultaneously the most smallest negative correlation coefficients in three lists. I did order negative correlation coefficients in increasing order. For instance, gene "IGF1R" meet my requirement.

Can anyone help me. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have data frames or lists? What is your requirement and why "IGF1R" meets it? In your example above there's not a unique gene that has the smallest correlation coefficient in all 3 data frames.

Comment: hi @AntonioK, I have three separate lists like the three separate figures. We can transform them to data frame easily, so I think it is not a problem. Besides, like I said, "I did order negative correlation coefficients in increasing order for each three list", it means, according to the interpretation of correlation coefficient, IGF1R will be strong downhill (negative) linear relationship with three clinical features of my interest. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but in your example you post the top 6 genes with the smallest estimate. Why not top 3? In that case IGF1R appears only in 1 data frame. Why not top 10? In that case other genes might appear as well. You must have something like a threshold or a philosophy behind what you define as "strong negative relationship".

Comment: @AntonioK yeah, Your right, I should consider about a threshold!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your items are data.frames, you can put them into a list and then work on each item at a time. This implementation finds the row with minimum `hp` and lists it. The result is a list, which you can collapse into a data.frame using `do.call`. If you want the origin of the item (i.e. from which data.frame it came from), the solution is a bit more involved, but nothing major.

Values in these

```
xy <- split(mtcars, f = mtcars$cyl)

out <- sapply(xy, FUN = function(x) {
  x[which.min(x$hp), ]
}, simplify = FALSE)

> out
$`4`
             mpg cyl disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Honda Civic 30.4   4 75.7 52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2

$`6`
         mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1

$`8`
                  mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Dodge Challenger 15.5   8  318 150 2.76 3.52 16.87  0  0    3    2

> do.call(rbind, out)
   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
4 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
6 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
8 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
```